# Error from the server ( 500 ) in an ASP.NET WebApi project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, endpoint, webapi

I have a ASP.NET WebApi project which runs on my localhost. However, on the hosting provider's server I get a 500 Internal server error. The try-catch block does not capture any Exception and the logger does not work, so I had to manually search for the line that is causing the issue by changing the location of the return of a response from the server. For whatever reason, on this line the server seems to crash by returning a 500 Internal Server Error:

```
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Usually this occurs when you do not have permission to access a resource on the server or the resource is missing.  The error needs to be debugged on the server, not the client.  You can check the event viewer on server to see if there is any errors.  Exceptions can only be caught once unless a THROW is added to a exception handler.  So most likely the error is already capture in a library and there is no throw.

Comment: When you get an error like 500 the body of the response is empty and then you are trying to access the empty body and getting an exception.  You should check response for 200 OK and if you do not check 200 OK than report an error instead of attempting to use the empty body.